# Django: Execute async Model manipulation tasks after getting a request

Tags: django, asynchronous

One part of my application requires fetching around 200 objects of a Model (Customer) to update certain fields on each and every request.

It first fetches a Customer object on every request and attains a list of Grouped Customers each with certain values from an outside API. This list of grouped customers has around 200 entries (each being of type Customer). I want to update all the Customer's fields with the values by fetching all 200 of them and updating and saving. Getting 200 objects for every single request and then waiting for it to finish updating then returning a response seems rather silly and slow. Is there anyway to do this updating asynchronously? Like I can return the response right after the I fetch the first Customer and then have a an async function handle the updating process.

Is there some possibility this can be done or do I have to wait for all 200 objects to be done updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first Google result for "django asynchronous tasks" would have shown you, the canonical way of doing this is to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org).

Comment: I did read upon before coming and asking but I wanted to get a second opinion. It reassures me when people confirm it like this. Thank You so much for your answer sir :)